# Static pointers that link objects in a chain

Tags: linked-list

In some legacy code that works perfectly fine the following method is used:

```
public class A
{
    public static A First;
    public static A Last;

    public A Next;
    public A Previous;

    public A() 
    {
        if (First == null) { First = this; }
        else { Previous = Last; Previous.Next = this; }
        Last = this;
    }
 }
```

This way all instances of type A are linked in order of creation, without using explicitly a linked list or whatever.

As a matter of fact I consider it an elegant solution, but I also suppose many objections can be made. Which objections should I consider?

Answer (score 0):

My main objection: it is not thread safe. If this algorithm is used in multiple threads the result is unpredictable